# MCS character mouth open - is this mo cap animation problem?

Tags: unity, c#, animation, character, motion-capture

I have [MCS Female Character](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/45807) where I can assigned Mocap to my character. I have downloaded [mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com) animation and assigned this to the character but the problem is, the character mouth remains open. I am not 3d artist or animation guy, so here are my question.

1. How can I solve mouth open problem in unity?
2. What is the reason that mouth is open? Either mocap data has open the mouth or what else problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go To **M3D character manager** component in your character
2. Go to **Advanced**
3. Check (True) **Force Jaw Shut**

Thanks to MCS team for answer